# memory allocation for non-static data members in class

Tags: c++

I am reading a article on gfg and came across this :

" Reason for initializing the const data member in initializer list is because no memory is allocated separately for const data member, it is folded in the symbol table due to which we need to initialize it in the initializer list."

please explain what is this symbol table and what is folding??
also why memory is not allocated to const data member.

Comment: can you provide a link to the article? Context might be relevant

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

The reason a non-static `const` data member needs to be initialized in a member initializer list, or with a default initializer, is simply because a `const` variable cannot be modified once the constructor *definition* is being executed:

```
struct S {
  int const i;
  S() {
    //  ... inside definition, i cannot be modified or assigned to
  }
};
```

But this is fine:

```
struct S {
  int const i;
  S() : i(42) {
  }
};
```

and this is also fine:

```
struct S {
  int const i = 42;
};
```

---

The quote about "folding the const variable into the symbol table" has nothing to do with the language rules. It's simply a potential optimization that a compiler might do. Even if the compiler doesn't do any "folding", the restriction on needing to initialize the `const` member (either with a default initializer, or in the member initializer list), before the constructor definition is executed  still applies.

Comment: but strictly speaking "const data members must be initialized using Initializer List" is wrong. Since c++11 there are default member initializers and primitive static members never **had** to appear in the initializer list

Comment: btw I am quoting from the link op provided in a comment

Comment: @idclev463035818 I didn't even read the link :p, but you're right. I've clarified the answer.